# Differences between jQuery's append and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not getting what `.wrap` does that `.append` doesn't.

If the main purpose of *wrap* is to add something around an element, I could easily stop using `.wrap` and use `.append`instead, right?

So, I'm using this test code to *append* something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $theWrapper = $('<div class="im-the-wrapper" />');
    var $theContent = $('<p>Me</p>');

    console.log($theWrapper.get(0));
    console.log($theContent.get(0));

    $('body').append($theContent);

    $theWrapper.append($theContent);

});

</script>
```

Result:

[image: Result for wrap]

And this test code to *wrap* things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $theWrapper = $('<div class="im-the-wrapper" />');
    var $theContent = $('<p>Me</p>');

    console.log($theWrapper.get(0));
    console.log($theContent.get(0));

    $('body').append($theContent);

    $theContent.wrap($theWrapper);

});

</script>
```

Result:

[image: Result for wrap]

I thought they would both return the exact same objects, but they don't. What's really happening in the background?

Comment: You're appending and then re-appending... I'd do this: `$('body').append($theWrapper.append($theContent))`

Comment: You realize you are logging to the console before you actually wrap or append, right?

Comment: Travis, that's one of the odd things here... the log does change depending on what I use.

Comment: The log does sometimes update after changes happen to a variable that you log, it's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your first code you're...

- putting the content into the DOM,
- taking the content out of the DOM and putting it into the wrapper *(which isn't in the DOM)*.

With the second, you're...

- putting the content in the DOM,
- then wrapping it in place, so that the wrapper ends up in the DOM as well

---

Given your example, a better solution than either of those would be to...

- append the content to the wrapper
- then append the wrapper to the DOM

```
$theWrapper.append($theContent).appendTo("body");
```

There's less manipulation happening that way.

---

The `.wrap()` method is really only used when there's something in place already that needs to be wrapped in a new Element.

Answer (score 2):

`element.wrap(wrapper)` basically does this:

```
element.before(wrapper);
wrapper.append(element);
```

That is why when you use `wrap` the element isn't lost, but when you do it manually without first appending the wrapper before the element, you end up just removing the elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`append` inserts content into the DOM at the end of the selected node.

`wrap` encloses the selected content in another node, not necessarily having any relationship to the DOM.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Awhkh/1/) (inspect the result)